# Why don't you need to use 'lift' when interacting with a nested StateT monadT in this case?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

Let's say I have a monadT:

```
type Wrap a = ReaderT Env ( StateT Int ( StateT Int Identity ) ) a
```

The important thing to note here is that one StateT is wrapping another, and both are wrapped inside a third MonadT, namely ReaderT.

and the corresponding runWrap function for convenience:

```
type Env = Map.Map Char Integer

runWrap :: Env -> Int -> Int -> Wrap a -> a
runWrap env st1 st2 m = runIdentity $ evalStateT ( evalStateT ( runReaderT m env ) st2 ) st1
```

And a generic tock state monad:

```
tock :: (Num s, MonadState s m) => m ()
tock = do modify (+1)
```

I now create a wrap monadT where inside I use tock:

```
aWrap :: Wrap ( Int, Int )
aWrap = do
    lift tock
    lift . lift $ tock
    x    <- get
    y    <- lift . lift $ get
    return ( x, y )
```

And run it:

```
env = Map.fromList [('x', 1)]
runWrap env 1 200 aWrap
// answer: (201,2)
```

The use of `lift` here makes sense to me in terms of my understanding of how to interact w/ nested layers of MonadT.

However, this also works and give me the same answer: `(201,2)`:

```
aWrap :: Wrap ( Int, Int )
aWrap = do
    tock
    lift . lift $ tock
    x    <- get
    y    <- lift . lift $ get
    return ( x, y )
```

I would think by calling `tock` w/o `lift`, it reads as if `tock` is applied to the outer MonadT, namely ReaderT, which makes no sense. But why does this work?

P.S. Please ignore the presence of `Env` here, it has nothing to do w/ the question, just the choice of the outer MonadT I'm using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your are likely using the `MonadState` typeclass without being aware of it. This typeclass is defined in the `mtl` package (and in `monads-fd`, too).

`MonadState` allows you to use the methods of the `State` monad, directly and without explicit lifting,  in many monad stacks based on `State`.

Look at the following two lines in the [haddocks](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Class.html):

```
Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m)
MonadState s m => MonadState s (ReaderT r m)
```

The first one says that any `StateT` is an instance of `MonadState` (as we should expect!). The second one says that any `ReaderT` whose base monad is an instace of `MonadState`, is also an instance of `MonadState`. Which happens to be your case.

Looking at the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#modify) for `MonadState`, we find:

```
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (ReaderT r m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
    state = lift . state

modify :: MonadState s m => (s -> s) -> m ()
modify f = state (\s -> ((), f s))
```

As you see, the inner machinery of the typeclass takes care of the lifting.

There are other typeclasses which offer similar functionality, like `MonadReader`, `MonadWriter` and `MonadRWS`.